# Attempting to add properties from an array into a text file in python?

Tags: python, arrays, text-files

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HF3mk.png)

I am trying to add the attributes to this text file on a new line, without it erasing previous data, so I am able to print the entire list of sets of data at the end

[Issue with my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEBBx.png)

as you can see, my code is not working due to the way in which I am trying to add and I have tried 5 different ways around this including adding the array to another array, to a dictionary and the raw array to the text file but none worked.

Comment: Post your code in your question. Avoid pasting links that might expire.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to debug that without the the full source but I'm going to make a guess: On line 158 did you mean to use "Potential_Rejections" rather than "Reasons_For_rejection"?

Answer (score 0):

As the name suggests, **UnboundLocalErrors** are only raised when improperly referencing an unassigned local variable.

In most cases this will occur when trying to modify a local variable before it is actually assigned within the local scope.

I am sure that you didn't assign 'Reason for rejection'....

Pls check the code